# Make textarea with text be same height as original div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Whenever I press edit on my div, it changes to textarea, but the textarea wont be same height as original text is and it adds scroll which I dont want, is there way I can make it the same height?
Ignore the v-if thing, it's from a framework, it's just for a state change.

[image: Div with text]

When I change my state for text to be in textarea
[image]

My html

```html
<div class="text-block border border-black p-4 flex mt-8 relative">
  <textarea class="p-2 rounded resize-none w-full shadow-none bg-transparent"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="flex-3" v-if="!clueEdit.has(clue.id)">
  <p> {{ description }} </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the working example at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Try fixing the height of textarea to h-56 and oultine-none